# urllib alongwith json to save to a variable

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Please correct my code. I am trying to save the result of this web page in json format to a variable in python.

---

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Varen/Desktop/json_v1.py", line 5, in <module>
    json.dump(link, f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 189, in dump
    for chunk in iterable:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 442, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <addinfourl at 53244992 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x032B4AF0>> is not JSON serializable
```

---

**Code**:

```
import urllib
import json
link = urllib.urlopen("http://www.saferproducts.gov/RestWebServices/Recall?RecallDateStart=2015-01-01&RecallDateEnd=2015-12-31&format=json")
with open('link.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(link, f)
```

Comment: It's right there in the error message: `not JSON serializable` - check the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the data from the file like object returned by `urlopen()`:

```
import urllib
import json

link = urllib.urlopen("http://www.saferproducts.gov/RestWebServices/Recall?RecallDateStart=2015-01-01&RecallDateEnd=2015-12-31&format=json")
with open('link.json', 'w') as f:
     json.dump(link.read(), f)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: It created an empty json file.

Comment: How many times did you read the data? It will be empty if you try to read it a second time because the data would already have been consumed by the first read. I've updated the answer with complete working code. If you paste it into a Python terminal it _should_ work.